# where to store thumbnails, DB or S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have lots of images stored in AWS s3. We plan to provide thumbnails for user to preview. If I store them in S3, I can only retrieve them one by one, which is not efficient. Show I store them in database? (I need query my database to decide which set of thumbnails to show the user to preview)

Comment: What do you mean by, "I can only retrieve them one by one"? You can store the URLs of the images in your database and show those instead.

Comment: @Blender what I mean is S3 does not provide an api like getObjectsByIds(Set<ObjectId> ids). I do store the URLs of the images in database and later I want to show the latest 30 images' thumbnails in one screen in iPhone. Now what I do is retrieve those thumbnails from S3 one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer depends on the usage pattern of the images.

For many applications, S3 would be the best choice for the simple reason that you can easily use S3 as an origin for CloudFront, Amazon's CDN.  By using CloudFront (or indeed any CDN), the images are hosted physically around the world and served from the fastest location for a given user.

With S3, you would not *retrieve* the images at all.  You would simply use S3's URL in your final HTML page (or the CloudFront URL, if you go that route).

If you serve images from the database, that increases resource consumption on the DB (more IO, more CPU, and some RAM used to cache image queries that is not available to cache other queries).

No matter which route you go, pre-create the thumbnail rather than producing it on the fly.  Storage space is cheap, and the delay to fetch (from S3 or the DB), process, then re-serve the thumbnail will lessen the user experience.  Additionally if you create the thumbnail on the fly, you cannot benefit from a CDN.

Comment: Thank you. I plan to store thumbnails in S3. But I'll show them in iPhone. Do you have suggestions on how to use CloudFront with iOS?

Comment: The image on CloudFront simply has a URL like any other image.  You can set things up so that the domain used by CloudFront is something like img.yourdomain.com.

Answer (score 2):

> If I store them in S3, I can only retrieve them one by one, which is not efficient.

No, it only looks inefficient because of the way you are using it.

S3 is massively parallel. It can serve your image to tens of thousands of simultaneous users without breaking a sweat. It can serve 100's of images to the same user in parallel -- so you can load 100 images in the same time it takes to load 1 image.  So why is your page slow?

Your browsers is trying to be a good citizen and only pull 2-4 images from a site at a time. This "serialization" is what is slowing you down and causing the bottleneck.

You can trick the browser by hosting assets on multiple domains. This is called "domain sharding". You can do it with multiple buckets (put images into 4 different buckets, depending on the last digit of their ID). Alternatively, you can do it with CloudFront: http://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/CloudFront-design-patterns-and-best-practices/

Comment: thank you. I viewed the link for the CloudFront best practices. But it suggest to generate thumbnails dynamically with EC2 instances. For my case, images will not change, so I'd prefer store static thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should store your static data in S3 & save their reference in Db.
In your particular case, you can save filename / hyperlink to the image file in a database that you can query upon depending on your business logic. 
This will give you reference to all the images that you can now fetch from S3 & display it to your users.
This can also help you to replace your reference to thumbnail depending on your need. For example, if you are running a e-commerce site, you can replace the thumbnail reference to point to new product image without much effort.
I hope this helps.